# Use the Settings API to whitelist a setting, but don't output it

Tags: settings-api

I have a plugin page with several settings. Four of this settings, all in the same section, need to be displayed inline rather than one above the other. However to ensure the settings are whitelisted, I must use the `add_settings_field()` function.

I can achieve most of my goal by passing a blank label and a callback to a function that outputs nothing for 3 of the options, and then add all four settings to the callback for the other. However doing so still adds a table row and thus leaves unnecessary white space for 3 of the options.

I've looked at the source of the `add_settings_field()` function, and all that does is add the setting to the `$wp_settings_fields` global. These settings are then output by the `do_settings_fields()` function, which has no obvious way of not outputting a table row.

Does anybody know of a way in which I can achieve all of my goal?

**Here is how I am registering the settings -**

```
/**
 * Register the settings that can be saved by this plugin
 */
public function register_plugin_settings(){

    add_settings_section(
        'aab_header_logo_section',                                      // ID
        __('What logo do you want to use?', 'djg-admin-area-branding'), // Title
        false,                                                          // Callback
        'djg_admin_area_branding_header'                                // Page
    );

    add_settings_field('header_logo_margin_top',//ID
        __('Header logo margin (px)', 'djg-admin-area-branding'), // Title
        array($this, '_option_header_logo_margin'),               // Callback
        'djg_admin_area_branding_header',                         // Page
        'aab_header_logo_section',                                // Section
        array(                                                    // Args
            'label_for' => 'header_logo_margin_top'
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'header_logo_margin_right',
        false,
        array($this, '_null'),
        'djg_admin_area_branding_header',
        'aab_header_logo_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'header_logo_margin_bottom',
        false,
        array($this, '_null'),
        'djg_admin_area_branding_header',
        'aab_header_logo_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'header_logo_margin_left',
        false,
        array($this, '_null'),
        'djg_admin_area_branding_header',
        'aab_header_logo_section'
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`register_setting()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) to whitelist an option. It won't affect the UI at all.

```
register_setting( 'my_option_group', 'my_option', 'optional_sanitize_callback' );
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I Did use register setting for each setting (should have added to question), and then I was also outputting each setting using `add_settings_field()`. So I'll just register one setting (`header_logo_margin`), make one call to `add_settings_field()`, and in the callback for that add four inputs with names like `header_logo_margin[top]`. Job done, thanks for the kick that made me think straight!